# React Dynamic Template with Form Control - Auto Correcting HTML Tag

Tags: html, reactjs, templates, dynamic, tags

hopefully someone there who can guide me on rite way. trying to create dynamic html with dynamic control. here is my example.

```
const [oHtml, setoHtml] = React.useState([
    {
      type: "html",
      control: "<table><tr><td>",
    },
    {
      type: "control",
      control: (
        <CustomInput
          labelText="Password"
          id="password"
          formControlProps={{
            fullWidth: true,
          }}
          inputProps={{
            type: "password",
            autoComplete: "off",
          }}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      type: "html",
      control: "</td></tr></table>",
    },
  ]);
```

and here how i am rendering.

```
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(oHtml).map(function (keyName, keyIndex) {
        if (oHtml[keyName].type === "html") {
          console.log(oHtml[keyName].control);
          return ReactHtmlParser(oHtml[keyName].control);    
        } else {
          return oHtml[keyName].control;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

issue is when React run `<table><tr><td>` its auto fixing tag and making it `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`

what i want to control inside td.

is there any way i can disable react to add missing tags itself?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `ReactHtmlParser` can't be used to parse partial html.

You can try

```
  return ReactHtmlParser(
    oHtml.map(v => v.control).join("")
  )
```

Btw, your `oHtml` is an array, so no need for `Object.keys`.

Comment: i have tried as you said example ```     {ReactHtmlParser("<table><tr><td>" + oHtml[1].control).join("") +
        "</td></tr></table>"} ''' now its showing ```[object Object]</td></tr></table>```

copied your code , and only showing [object Object]